# Why is XmlDocument.Load(url) returning a stale file?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-1.1

I have an application written in .NET 1.1 that calls XmlDocument.Load on a URL.  Just recently the xml file was updated.  Now whenever I call XmlDocument.Load, the old file is returned.  When I hit the same URL from a browser, I see the new file.  I deleted all temporary files from IE and I still see the same issue.  Any thoughts on why I am seeing a older version of the file when I access it programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but try clearing your IE's browser cache. .NET HTTP is sitting on top of the same stack as IE and also share proxy settings, so I would not be surprised if the cache is shared, too.

Comment: Doing the download oneself using HttpWebRequest it is possible to set the caching policy to RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache.

Answer (score 1):

delete also the ASP.net temporary files

Comment: Did you clear the browser cache (i.e. delete temporary files in IE)?

Comment: How is the file being served?

Comment: via an intranet web server. From IE I can see the new file, but doing an XmlDocument.Load still returns the old one.

Comment: maybe this sounds weird but search for the file in the application data folder under document and Settings\User\ApplicationData

Comment: Then I have no further input, short of running a sniffer to check if the request is going to the right place, and searching the local disk for a copy of the file.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that there must have been some caching on the proxy and this cleared up by itself in 48 hours.